# Есть нормальный способ реализовать REGEXP поиск в MariaDB по json'у?

Tags: sql, json, база-данных, mariadb

Есть поле в БД с типом json. Есть ли возможность реализовать поиск по значениям по типу REGEXP без участия ЯП.

Comment: mysql не поддерживает десириализацию json

Comment: Скорее да, чем нет. Выложите пример данных в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, критерий поиска, требуемый результат. И укажите точную версию MySQL.